# Encode accentuated characters in json using php

Tags: php, utf-8, json

I've a query result that contains some accentuated characters  Like :

```
CollectionTitle => Afleuréss
```

But when i write a `json` file with `json_encode($Result_Array)` and retrieve the result it shows :

```
CollectionTitle => NULL
```

then i used `array_map()` :

```
$res[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
```

But it results me :

`CollectionTitle => AfleurÃ©ss` instead of  `CollectionTitle => Afleuréss`

Please suggest me better way to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Add to your HTML head:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Note that you should have a proper HTML doctype because browsers default to non utf8. You can do a simple test, like I did, this works:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<?php
$title = "Jérôme";
echo $title."<br>";
```

But the place for the meta tag is in the head tag. The HTML document should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>An XHTML 1.0 Strict standard template</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>

<?php
$title = "Jérôme";
echo $title."<br>";
?>
```

That is standard.

Answer (score 2):

The second one is actually the correct one. The problem is your browser cannot detect the encoding and defaults to whatever the default is (probably ISO-8859-1). Switch your browser encoding and you'll see the right character appear.

Comment: It doesn't make sense for him to declare UTF-8 because his other data is in Windows-1252. There is no way to win here except move over to UTF-8 or not use JSON.

Answer (score 1):

`json_encode` only supports UTF-8, but the rest of your app is using Windows-1252. I don't suggest using `utf8_encode` as that converts from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. That only works 95% of the time for you because you are using Windows-1252, not ISO-8859-1*.

I don't know if it's possible for you but if you can, you should switch over to UTF-8 so you don't need this fragile conversion code anywhere.

*This is probably confusing. Browsers [do not actually allow you to use ISO-8859-1](http://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#legacy-single-byte-encodings) and instead treat it as Windows-1252. Same with MySQL, Latin1 means Windows-1252. Both are defaults. `utf8_encode/decode` of course use actual `ISO-8859-1`, so it's incompatible in the 0x80-0x9F range.

Answer (score 0):

In your second example / step:

```
$res[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
```

It looks like you're trying to encode in `UTF-8` something that is **not** `ISO-8859-1`.

You should detect / know what's the encoding coming from your Database, and transcode it properly to `UTF-8` with [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) for example.

As an alternative, you should know:

- What is the encoding in the Database?
- What is the encoding of the PHP files?
- What is the encoding in the HTML page? `<meta charset="utf-8">`

And if that's possible, move all of the above to `UTF-8`...